# moving temporary value using rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to lean move semantics and I wrote this example. I would like to move a temporary r-value into an object on stack.

```
class MemoryPage
{
    public:

    size_t size;
    MemoryPage():size(0){
    }
    MemoryPage& operator= (MemoryPage&& mp_){
        std::cout << "2" <<std::endl;
        size = mp_.size;
        return *this;
    }
};
MemoryPage getMemPage()
{
    MemoryPage mp;
    mp.size = 4;
    return mp;
}
int main() {
    MemoryPage mp;
    mp = getMemPage();
    std::cout << mp.size;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error at the return of getMemPage():

```
error: use of deleted function 'constexpr MemoryPage::MemoryPage(const MemoryPage&)'
```

Comment: The copy (and move) constructors of `MemoryPage` are implicitly defined as deleted / not declared because you provide a custom move assignment-operator. Returning an object, as in `return mp;` requires either a copy or a move constructor (even if it is not called). Make sure to follow the rule of five.

Comment: See [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

Comment: By the way, the error message should've told you what DyP did. Not sure if you cropped it for the purposes of the question. `note: 'constexpr MemoryPage::MemoryPage(const MemoryPage&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'MemoryPage' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is:

> [...] defined as deleted if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - T has a user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator

In order to solve the immediate problem, you simply provide a copy constructor, i.e.:

```
MemoryPage(const MemoryPage&) { }
```

However, as noted in the comments, it's a good idea to consult [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) . In particular, this paragraph summarizes what issues you may run into if you neglect to provide any of the special member functions:

> Note that:
>
> - move constructor and move assignment operator won't be generated for a class that explicitly declares any of the other special member
>     functions
> - copy constructor and copy assignment operator won't be generated for a class that explicitly declares a move constructor or move assignment
>     operator
> - a class with a explicitly declared destructor and implicitly defined copy constructor or implicitly defined copy assignment operator is
>     considered deprecated.

<sub>formatted for readability</sub>

Therefore it is good practice when writing a class that deals with memory management to provide all five special member functions, i.e.:

```
class C {
  C(const C&) = default;
  C(C&&) = default;
  C& operator=(const C&) & = default;
  C& operator=(C&&) & = default;
  virtual ~C() { }
};
```

Comment: You can even default the virtual dtor.

Comment: I think an important part of the answer is *where* a copy/move ctor is required in the OP's code.